# pass list of objects from view to controller in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding checkboxes to every object in a List. When I try to return the values back to the controller the list is empty and I only get the checkbox bool.

Can someone explain to me how to pass the List correctly from the view to the controller.

I tried it with form but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

I searched a lot on Google and also found similar posts on stackoverflow but I couldn't find one that helped me.

**View**

```
@model List<WCFasp.net.WCF.Person> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowView";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Check", "Home"))
{
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
        <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsChecked) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)</p>
        }
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Check(List<WCF.Person> selectedpersonlist)
        {
            //Here I get the empty list

            return View("ShowSelectedView");
        }
```

**Person**

```
[DataContract]
    public class Project
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        public Project(string name, bool isChecked)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.IsChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }
```

*Little question at the end. Am I getting down voted because I am not a pro or is there another reason?*

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Any exceptions? One thing comes to mind is the model has a constructor which mvc does not handle well

Comment: no errors. no exceptions. Anything in my list is just empty except for the checkbox value.

Comment: So the list is not empty? It only contains the set values for `IsChecked`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want more properties populated within your list then you can use hidden fields to store the information:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
    <p>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsChecked) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)</p>
}
```